# C# Linq Query - Groupby

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable that holds data as such:

```
Date OperationA OperationB OperationC

Today    5
Today               6
Today                          7
```

Now, I want this to look like:

```
Date OperationA OperationB OperationC

Today    5          6          7
```

I've had a look at the LINQ Group by clause, but that seems to seperate the data that is being grouped and doesn't keep it within the collection - althought as a LINQ novice, I may be missing something.

Could somebody please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: is the array always sparse like this? Meaning each row only contains 1 operation and each column only contains one operation?

Comment: For the operation and results yes.  This is the result of a pivot, from  a column containing all operations and it's corresponding column containg it's result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Operation
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int OperationA { get; set; }
    public int OperationB { get; set; }
    public int OperationC { get; set; }
}

var operations = LoadData();
var result = operations.GroupBy(o => o.Date)
                   .Select(g => new Operation
                    {
                        Date = g.Key,
                        OperationA = g.Sum(o => o.OperationA),
                        OperationB = g.Sum(o => o.OperationB),
                        OperationC = g.Sum(o => o.OperationC)
                    });
```

P.S: You DB design looks weird. I think the table should look like this:

```
Date       Operation     Type
2010-1-1      5           A
2010-1-1      6           B
2010-1-1      7           C
```

Comment: @Darren Yes, if possible I would very much recommend to review the schema design of the DB. The design will add complexity and bugs to your code, having a good reasonably normalized DB schema will help a lot and make you queries much simpler and robust against changes.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ *projects* - that is, it produces a new sequence based on the input sequence. In other words, it is always read-only, it never writes, never modifies the original sequence, and never has side-effects.

Secondly, `GroupBy` produces an `IGrouping`, which is a special kind of `IEnumerable<T>` with an extra property called `Key` - that's the single value those items have in common, and were grouped by.

So in your case, GroupBy will create a data structure that is slightly closer to the final goal, by clustering rows by date:

```
var operationClusters = myDataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().GroupBy(row => row["Date"]);
```

But you still need to provide the logic for collapsing the values into a single row - for example, `5` is the wanted value and `null` is not for OperationA column.

Comment: Aah okay - I never knew that.   Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is relevant. The question is about how to 'flatten' the data. Database "holds data" that the OP wants "to look" flattened.